# Inetgrating iReport(with large no of sub reports) with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jasper-reports, report, ireport

My current application includes a functionality of displaying a report designed in iReports 4.1.1 from Spring MVC at front and using PostgreSQL at back.

Now i am more of concerned about its performance issues.

The Main report which will display data has as many as 20 subreports at most.
and each subreport has high cost query running for it.

So what are the chances of having performance issues when the user count increases (in short when application scales)??
And if there is any such potential problem in coming, what are the remedies??

Also one vary naive doubt: do i need to use jasperserver or just integrate the JRXML directly (what i am just doing now)? does it affect performance anyway??
Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use the JRXML approach (I'd rather use the pre-compiled .JASPER file, as the report file doesn't need to be compiled at server-runtime), all Jasper-Related stuff is running inside your application. If you are using the Jasper Server then it'll run in it's own webapp, depending on how you configured and started JasperServer.

The thing is, I'm not sure if Spring provides a "plug-and-play" solution for integrating JasperServer, but you still can use the approach to write all the Jasper-Code yourself.

Comment: Thanks Robert for reply..
thing is i am using jaspers only.. No JRXML in classpath..
but as i am new to both ireport and spring i was making sure as the user list grow performance dont start declining..

and do you have any idea how i can integrate spring and jasper server so jasper handles reporting stuff and mvc does what it actually meant to..??
thanks again:)

Comment: well what I do with my reporting stuff is that the generation of my reports are running in a method with Spring's @Async annotation. Which means that the jasper export is running parallel to the http-request and don't blocks it. If you can use this depends on how you need your reports. In my case, I use it to generate all the invoices for my customers and to generate some reports that don't get accessed for ~1 second, which is usually enough to get the export done.